# How can I rearrange the chars in a char*?

Tags: iphone, c, string, indexing, char

I have `char* myChar = "HELLO"`. I would like to switch the places of the E and the O. I tried doing `myChar[1] = myChar[4]`, but that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Memory error. Thanks for your time, but Tim Cooper helped me

Comment: Please update your question (and title) with the exact error message/symptom so that it can be useful to people in the future.

Comment: EXE_BAD_ACCESS error. That's all output but that is not my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, that string literal is probably being stored in read-only memory. You can fix that by declaring the string as an array of characters:

```
char myChar[] = "HELLO";
```

To swap the characters, you'll have to use a temporary variable:

```
char c1 = myChar[1];
myChar[1] = myChar[4];
myChar[4] = c1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned whatever is in `myChar[4]` into `myChar[1]`. (that's all you did there)
You need to create a temporary variable `char temp;` and do the following:

```
Edit: As mentioned by Tim Cooper, char myChar[] = "HELLO"; - // This will remove it's constness.
temp = myChar[1];
myChar[1] = myChar[4];
myChar[4] = temp;
```

This is a very common 'algorithm' to swap two things.

Comment: That won't solve his main problem -- he's trying to modify a pointer to a constant.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah quite correct fine sir, i shall edit the answer.